# Why is my Google Tag Manager event expecting this `_event` value?

Tags: google-tag-manager

We've set up a Google Tag Manager trigger for successful signups. We've configured it like this:

```
Trigger type: Other - Custom Event
Event name: Successful Signup
This trigger fires on : Some Custom Events
Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true
Event equals successful_signup
```

[image: screenshot from google tag manager trigger configuration]

We fire the event using custom JavaScript like this:

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'successful_signup'})
```

When we inspect the page, it looks like the event is firing, but it's applying an additional condition that we didn't specify: `_event equals Successful Signup`.

[image: screenshot from browser plugin]

Why is this extra condition being applied?

Answer (score 6):

## The Event Name matters

We thought that the "Event Name" was just a human-readable label, but apparently it actually has to match what is sent by JS. Changing it to match what's sent by JavaScript (`dataLayer.push({'event': 'successful_signup'})`) got it working.

[image: screenshot from google tag manager renaming event]